# SSRS DateTime Parameter in URL

Tags: reporting-services

I am passing the following URL in order to load a report in SSRS.  There are two parameters in the report:

```
http://servername/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fReports%2fApplications%2fPersonnel%2fRptNameChange&ssn=#########&txtEffectiveDate=06/01/2012
```

**Parameters**

1. String - ssn
2. DateTime - txtEffectiveDate

However, when the page loads, it is as if the parameters are not recognized and it loads the page with empty fields in the parameters.

What is missing or incorrect about the URL?  Thanks!

Comment: If you're still working wherever you were back when you posted this, please stop sending people's Social Security Numbers in plain text over unencrypted protocols. Smh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was calling the Report Manager URL, instead of the Web Service URL.

Here was the working version of the SSRS Url:
`http://servername/ReportServer?/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/`

In order to complete the call to the SSRS Web Service Url, attach the report name and any parameters that are needed to run the report:

`http://servername/ReportServer?/Folder1/Folder2/Folder3/ReportName&Param1=12345`

Answer (score 2):

You're so close! You should be able to pull this off by changing Report.aspx to ReportViewer.aspx. For example, see below:

```
http://servername/Pages/**ReportViewer.aspx?**ItemPath=%2fReports%2fApplications%2fPersonnel%2fRptNameChange&ssn=#########&txtEffectiveDate=06/01/2012
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael.  I was able to get it fixed.  I did not try your solution, but thank you for taking time to respond.