# Requesting Report with URL Parameters

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, url-parameters

My issue is exactly the same as Mr. John Ortega's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235302/ssrs-datetime-parameter-in-url).

However, both of the proposed solutions have not worked for me.

If I replace "Report.aspx" with "ReportViewer.aspx" in the Report Manager URL (ex: "http://servername/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fFolder+1+Name%2fFolder+2+Name%2fReport+Name"), I'm given a 404.

If I use the Web Service URL structure instead (ex: "http://servername/Reports?/Folder 1 Name/Folder 2 Name/Report Name"), I just get redirected back to the home page of my report server (which is "http://servername/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx").

So I'm not really given an opportunity to pass report parameters via URL parameters, because the report itself won't come up.

Comment: goto `http://servername/reportserver`, then to your report - you will get the correct url with reportviewer.aspx

Comment: /ReportServer did the trick.  Thank you sir!

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement to jump to any other report in the same report server and directory, you can use “go to report” option instead of using “go to URL”.